# Can't partition hard drive - "corrupt", exit code 8

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I want to install Windows on a partition of my Mac's SSD. Therefore, I had BootCamp install Windows from an .iso file.
Unfortunately, BootCamp could not partition my drive. The error message doesn't say much; it just asks me to repair my drive via First Aid in Disk Utility.

I ran first aid on the physical disk. Result:

[image: check ok]

Next, I ran first aid on the logical volume. Result:

[image: first aid failed]

As suggested, I decided to run first aid from recovery. Since Disk Utility in recovery mode only lets me run first aid on the physical disk, the result is as expected: everything's ok.

Then, I tried manually creating a partition to boot into using a bootable USB. Disk Utility gave the following output:

[image: partitioning failed]

Now, I'm not sure how serious I should take the message *"the volume xxx is corrupt and needs to be repaired"*, since the first aid on the physical disk says, everything is fine.

Any idea what's causing this and how I can resolve it?
If possible, I'd rather not reformat the drive, except if it's necessary.

---

#### Edit:

As requested by @klanomath, I ran the command `sudo gpt -r show disk0` in terminal. This is the output:

```
    start       size  index  contents
        0          1         PMBR
        1          1         Pri GPT header
        2         32         Pri GPT table
       34          6         
       40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
   409640  975425848      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
975835488    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
977105024          3         
977105027         32         Sec GPT table
977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

---

#### Edit #2:

In internet recovery mode, I ran the command `diskutil list`, which returned this list:

[image: result of diskutil list]

I was not sure whether I should use `disk1` or `disk2`, so I tried running `diskutil verifyVolume diskX` on both of them. For `disk1`, I received a message saying `invalid request`. For `disk2`, the following result and error message was displayed:

[image: result of diskutil verifyVolume disk2]

I then tried running the command `diskutil repairVolume diskX`, again for both disks. Same error message for `disk1`, following output for `disk2`:

[image: result of diskutil repairVolume disk2]

Comment: Reformatting might be the least expensive way to "fix" the issue. Other solutions that I can think of involve 3rd party disk utilities like DiskWarrior or DriveGenius.

Comment: @SteveChambers, if I ignore the error (and obviously don’t install Windows), will this error affect my machine in any other way?

Comment: It looks like the error is on the Mac side. Just like a cut, if you ignore it it might heal or it might get infected. I always have an updated copy of Diskwarior on hand for the (rare) times this happens. I *never* ignore disk errors.

Comment: Ha, love the analogy. So, should I rather try the 3rd party apps you’ve mentioned, or reformat my drive?

Comment: I would go with the disk utility but reformatting is cheaper, though time consuming. Also klanomath may have some suggestions, he's better at disk utility via command line than I am...

Comment: Right, so as you can see in the first image of the 2nd edit, there’s a disk w/ the id `disk1` that’s 500.3GB big. Running the verify command for `disk1`, gives me this error: *"Error starting file system verification for disk1: invalid request (-69886)"*. Running the same command for `disk1s2`, however, actually finishes the verification. Same for the repair command. - @klanomath

Comment: Well that’s what I’m saying: the only disk with a comparable size is disk1. When I scroll down, there’s only disks with a few kilo- or megabytes. @klanomath

Comment: Nothing. There’s no result.

Comment: Your main volume isn't mounted! Enter `diskutil cs list`. With the UUID of the Logical Volume enter `diskutil cs unlockVolume UUID`. Then `diskutil list` and with the disk identifier of the now mounted main volume `diskutil verifyVolume diskX`.

Comment: Cool, that seemed to do it. It‘s disk18. It found the incorrect block count has "successfully repaired the volume". I’ll see how the partitioning goes and get back to you. Thanks so far! @klanomath

Comment: Perfect! I can now partition my drive. Thanks so much, @klanomath. Post an answer, if you wish, and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main volume has a minor error (orphaned blocks - invalid volume free block count) which usually can be fixed with `diskutil repairVolume diskIdentifier` entered in Terminal.app booted from another volume or disk.

- Either boot to Recovery Mode (<kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting) or Internet Recovery Mode (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> while booting).
- In the menubar > Utilities open Terminal
- Enter `diskutil list` to get the disk identifier of your main volume.

  - with CoreStorage disabled that's usually disk0s2
  - with CoreStorage enabled that's usually disk2 or in the upper tenth (e.g. disk17). It's the one with the *(internal, virtual)* supplement.

    If it wasn't mounted enter `diskutil cs list` to get the Logical Volume UUID and try to mount it with `diskutil cs unlockVolume UUID` (replace UUID here with the UUID found previously). Repeat `diskutil list` to get the disk identifier.
- Now check the volume with `diskutil verifyVolume diskXsY` (normal volume) or `diskutil verifyVolume diskX` (CoreStorage volume).
- Then try to repair the volume with `diskutil repairVolume diskXsY` (normal volume) or `diskutil repairVolume diskX` (CoreStorage volume).